# How can I update where a given select condition returns a true value?

Tags: mysql, sql, sql-update

I want to perform an SQL update

```
UPDATE  incCustomer SET etaxCode = 'HST' WHERE
```

only on records where this is true.

```
select  etaxCode
from  incCustomer
left join incAddress on incCustomer.iAddressId = incAddress.iId
left join incProvince on incAddress.iProvinceStateId = incProvince.iId
where incAddress.iProvinceStateId in (     2  ,     3   ,      4   ,    6   ,   9 )
```

I don't think that this is possible with ANSI SQL,  but can it be done in MySQL?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[MySQL UPDATE syntax](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/update.html) supports joins in both ANSI-89 and ANSI-92 syntax.

Use:

```
   UPDATE INCCUSTOMER c
LEFT JOIN INCADDRESS a ON a.iid = c.iaddressid
LEFT JOIN INCPROVINCE p ON p.iid = a.iprovincestateid
      SET c.etaxcode = 'HST'
    WHERE a.iProvinceStateId IN (2,3,4,6,9)
```

I don't see the point of LEFT JOINing to the province table - I think your UPDATE could be written as:

```
   UPDATE INCCUSTOMER 
      SET c.etaxcode = 'HST'
    WHERE EXISTS(SELECT NULL
                   FROM INCADDRESS a
                  WHERE a.iid = INCCUSTOMER.iaddressid
                    AND a.iProvinceStateId IN (2,3,4,6,9))
```

Comment: Though I should point out that OUTER joins in ANSI-89 require vendor specific syntax, and I don't know that MySQL ever had such syntax.